# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error in HTTPS request

Tags: vue.js, https

I have a standard HTTPS Axios request from my Frontend (which is based on Vue), to the our company's API which is on another server(server use SSL sertificate).

```
testApi() {

 axios.get('https://rng-hub2.staging.rng:8001/rng/3/')
      .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
      // always executed
  });


},
```

Which cause an error like this:
In Firefox:
[image]

In Chrome the error looks like this:

[image]

As I was thinking, in browsed developing tools under tab of Netwerk -> Response, I should also see an error, which is true for Chrome, but eventyally is not true for Firefox.
So Chrome shows me:

[image]

But in the Firefox I receive my data in exactly right format:

[image]

Have any idea how I can retrieve this data correctly and assign it to the response variable in .then section?

About Cross-Origin Request Blocked error: API's server administrator told me, that he have added my IP to the CORS "trusted list". However I'm not sure, because according to this post: https://jonhilton.net/cross-origin-request-blocked/
in my  Response Header I should receive an additional header with my local IP like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://192.168.32.44
```

But I'm not.

This proxy staff also didn't work:
[How to deal with CORS error on Vue CLI 3?](https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3)

Please give me hint what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was deeper then I thought. So short answer is: If you are working in local network, with different API servers, they might be certified with inner corporate CA (Certificate authority) to be able to communicate via HTTPS protocol. So what you need is, to ask from your server administrator to give you private_key with which you gonna sign all the request to a specific API. In guzzle its looks like this:

```
new GuzzleClient(['verify' => '/path/to/self-signed/cert.pem']);
```